# Number of zeroes of $z^{2}-z+2=(z-\frac{1}{2})^{2}+\frac{7}{4}$ in unit disk using the Argument principle or Rouche

Tags: complex-analysis

Just using the discriminant the roots are $\frac{1}{2}(1+\pm \sqrt{7})$, so it has no zeroes in the unit disk. But I am wondering how to show it with Argument principle or Rouches for my tutorial:

$p(e^{it})=e^{i2t}(1-e^{-it}+2e^{-2it})$

With Rouches it is not clear what choice of f would do ,if any, s.t. $|f-p(z)|<|f|$. Ideally some f, whose argument we can easily identify. For example, $f(z)=\frac{7}{4}$ doesn't work because $|f-g|=|z-\frac{1}{2}|^{2}\leq 9/4$.

Using the Argument principle gives:

$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{2z-1}{z^{2}-z+2}dz$

but evaluating that requires either finding the poles or Taylor expanding.

Answer (score 0):

No need for so sophisticated tools : your roots $\frac{1}{2}(1\pm i\sqrt{7})$ (I have added the $i$...) have a common module (=absolute value=norm) which is

$\sqrt{1/4+7/4}=\sqrt{2}>1$ : thus, they are both outside the unit disk.

Comment: "But I am wondering how to show it with other methods "

Answer (score 0):

You can argue that for $|z| < 1$,

$$z^2 - z + 2 = 0 \implies |z||z - 1| = 2 \implies 2 < |z - 1| \le |z| + 1 < 2$$

A contradiction.